# Rational class for java can't run program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rational-number

So we have to create a Rational class that does the following. Create a project in Java that includes a Rational class.  The class represents Rational numbers.  It should have only 2 fields num and denom.  It should have the following public methods (and any other private methods needed):

- A constructor that takes a num and denom (in that order) as initial field values. If denom is 0, set the number to 0/1.
- An accessor for num (getNum)
- An accessor for denom (getDenom)
- A toString method that returns String of the form "num/denom" (no spaces) where num and denom have the stored values
- An add method that takes a Rational number r and returns a Rational number that is the result of adding r to this Rational number.  It should not change this rational number.
- (Extra credit - 2 points) A reduce method with no arguments that reduces this Rational number to lowest form.

I have code that I have done in Intellij IDEA but it will not let me run the program. I know that I am getting errors for most things but I believe it is just because I am not putting something in the correct place or leaving something out. This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rational {

    private int num;
    private int den; //fields

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("")

        public Rational( int n, int d){

            num = n;
            den = d;

            if (d == 0) {
                num = 0;
                den = 1;

                System.out.println("Denominator is 0. Enter a number other than 0 next time.");

            }//close if

            int g = gcd(num, den);
            num = n / g;
            den = d / g;

        }//close Rational

    public String toString() {

        if (den == 1) {
            return num + "";

        } else {

            return num + "/" + den;

        }

    }//close toString

    private Rational add(Rational r) {

        int newNum = (this.num * r.den) + (r.num * this.den);
        int newDen = r.den * this.den;
        return new Rational(newNum, newDen);

    }//close add

    private static int gcd(int m, int n) {

        if (0 == n) {
            return m;

        } else {

            return gcd(n, m % n);

        }//close else

    }//close gcd

}//close main

}//close class
```

Comment: What does 'will not let me run the program' mean? What is happening when you run it?

Comment: Why can't you just read the error message?

`file.java:12: error: ';' expected System.out.println ("")`

Pretty obvious why it fails.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase Where did you find the error message? I don't see anything in the post. Either way, thanks for the info.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase I fixed the semi colon issue with System.out.println ("") and still no luck. Not sure where to begin.

Comment: For one, why is your rational class inside your main method?

Comment: @Natecat Didn't realize that. I have made a new Main class with      public class Main {

    public static void main (String [] args){


    }
}                                                                                                                                                                                 And I have gotten rid of public static void main (String [] args) { } in the rational class. But I still cannot run it.

Comment: Oh I meant why is the constructor for your rational class inside your main method, there's no reason to make a new class

Comment: @Natecat My class has been using BlueJ but I was asking around and they told me about IntelliJ IDEA so I got it. In BlueJ everything had a template but here it's not that way. I have not dealt with public static void main (String [] args) before so I looked what I could up online about it and just placed it there in my code. When I took out the main method it got rid of all of the errors in the rational class, I just still can't run it.

Comment: BlueJ is a crutch. I recommend you relearn Java basics. Can you be more detailed about what happens when you try to run it and update your OP

Comment: I edited this question for a reason - so that the syntax highlighting would at least work, and to remove the code snippets since that does not work with Java.  Also, I made your requirements section a bit more readable.

Comment: @Natecat Can you recommend a good place for me to relearn the basics? BlueJ has been hindering me for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public Rational(int n, int d){ // put Your Constructor Out of the main First
         num = n;
         den = d;

         if (d == 0) {
            num = 0;
            den = 1;
            System.out.println("Denominator is 0. Enter a number other than 0 next time.");
        }//close if
         int g = gcd(num, den);
         num = n / g;
         den = d / g; 
       }//close Rational
    }

  public String toString() {  //put methods Outside of Main
                if (den == 1) {
                    return num + "";
                } else {

                    return num + "/" + den;

                }

            }//close toString

     private Rational add(Rational r) {   //put methods Outside of Main

          int newNum = (this.num * r.den) + (r.num * this.den);
          int newDen = r.den * this.den;
          return new Rational(newNum, newDen);
     }//close add

    private static int gcd(int m, int n) {  //put methods Outside of Main
                if (0 == n)
                    return m;
                else
                    return gcd(n, m % n);        
            }//close gcd

    public static void main (String [] args) { //here is your Main Method.

            System.out.println("");

            // call Your Methods Accordingly. 

        } // main Closed
    } //class Closed
```

1. You have put Constructor into the `main` Method. It should be out of the main box.
2. Each method that you Defined is exists within the `main` Method. Again a Compilation Error .
3. You can call these methods From inside of `main` either using any class `object` (If Instance method) or using Class Name directly (If Static Method).

Comment: ***Explain*** the problem.  Don't just leave a bunch of code for someone to pick through.

Comment: I have also provide comments to explain the Problem @Makoto Thanks. I have Added the Problem as a `text` Too.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap Thank you. I am, as you can tell, new to Java, and new to programming as a whole and my class has not taught us how to use a real compiler such as IntelliJ IDEA as we have been using BlueJ but I wanted to learn real programming so I could learn more on my own. Thanks!